# Forcing www and https redirect on NGINX as backend of Google cloud Load Balancer using $http_x_forwarded_proto

Tags: web, nginx, redirect, google-cloud-load-balancer

I have a NGINX backend instance for the google cloud platform load balancer. I have and have successfully set up the https redirect. I want to force from non-www to www. For the most part all but one instance redirects to a www url. to Summarize:

https://ampkart.com not successful and stays as https://ampkart.com

I have tried multiple edits to the redirect in the default.conf file to force it but to no avail. I know it probably has something to 'http' in the 
  bracket and it is only affecting the http urls to redirect to www but the https urls are not affected. Can someone please help me modify this code for the redirect to work? Here is my default.conf file for my NGINX server.

```
 server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /storage;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name ampkart.com;


        location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                error_page  405     =200 $uri;
        }

        # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {

            if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = 'http'){
            rewrite  ^/(.*)$  https://www.ampkart.com/$1 permanent;
        }               
                    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        #   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
        #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        if ($request_method ~* "(GET|POST|OPTIONS)") {
                    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "GET, POST, 
        OPTIONS";
                    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" "true";
                    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" 
         "https://www.ampkart.com";
                    add_header "Access-Control-Expose-Headers" "AMP- 
         Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin,Content-Length,Content-Range";
                    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User- 
         Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content- 
         Type,Range';
                    add_header 'AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin' 
         "https://www.ampkart.com";
                    add_header "AMP-Same-Origin" "true";
                    add_header "AMP-Redirect-to" 
         "https://www.ampkart.com$request_uri";
              }   
            }

          # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
          # concurs with nginx's one
          #
          location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
          }
          }
```

I would like to be able to redirect https://ampkartcom to https://www.ampkart.com

Answer (score 0):

Solved. If you are trying to implement forced https and www or non-www with a nginx backend of Google cloud load balancer, just use the cold below: Place it underneath the server_name, change example.com to your domain.

```
if ($http_host ~* '^example.com'){ 
rewrite ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com$request_uri redirect; }
```

this will force https with the nginx backend and if you don't want the www and want to force non-www, just remove the "www."

Also, here is a full default.conf for my website nginx backend of the google cloud load balancer with php-fpm enabled. Enjoy!

```
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/
# https://wiki.debian.org/Nginx/DirectoryStructure
#
# In most cases, administrators will remove this file from sites-enabled/ and
# leave it as reference inside of sites-available where it will continue to be
# updated by the nginx packaging team.
#
# This file will automatically load configuration files provided by other
# applications, such as Drupal or Wordpress. These applications will be made
# available underneath a path with that package name, such as /drupal8.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    #listen 443 ssl default_server;
    #listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;


        #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /www;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name www.example.com;     

if ($http_host ~* '^example.com'){ 
rewrite ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com$request_uri redirect; } 

                location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            error_page  405     =200 $uri;
}

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {  

                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    #   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

}

# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#   listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80;
#
#   server_name example.com;
#
#   root /var/www/example.com;
#   index index.html;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}
```